# How to make a HTTPrequest in JSONP callback?

Tags: web-application, xss, json, content-security-policy, jsonp

I'm trying an XSS challenge. I found an exploit that breaks CSP by using a JSONP callback. I can get an alert to pop up by putting something like:

```
<script src="https://whitelisted.jsonp?callback=alert#1"></script>
```

But I'm having trouble trying to get it to send an HTTP-request. I've tried putting functions changing `window.location`, but it doesn't seem to execute any of my anon functions.

Comment: ahh, I got it by using a different jsonp endpoint that allows me to just put window.location.replace

Comment: I'm glad you were able to solve your problem. Please write an answer down below that roughly describeds how you solved the problem, in case others run into the same or a similar situation.